# Getting DirectoryNotFoundException when trying to Connect to Device with CoreCon API

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-mobile, compact-framework, corecon

I'm trying to use the CoreCon API in Visual Studio 2008 to programmatically launch device emulators. When I call `device.Connect()`, I inexplicably get a DirectoryNotFoundException. I get it if I try it in PowerShell or in C# Console Application. Here's the code I'm using:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     DatastoreManager dm = new DatastoreManager(1033);
     Collection<Platform> platforms = dm.GetPlatforms();

     foreach (var p in platforms)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", p.Name, p.Id);
     }

     Platform platform = platforms[3];
     Console.WriteLine("Selected {0}", platform.Name);

     Device device = platform.GetDevices()[0];
     device.Connect();
     Console.WriteLine("Device Connected");

     SystemInfo info = device.GetSystemInfo();
     Console.WriteLine("System OS Version:{0}.{1}.{2}",info.OSMajor, info.OSMinor, info.OSBuildNo);

     Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error? I'm running this on WinXP 32-bit, plain jane Visual Studio 2008 Pro. I imagine it's some config issue since I can't do it from a Console app or PowerShell.

Here's the stack trace:

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException was unhandled

Message="The system cannot find the path specified.\r\n"

Source="Device Connection Manager"

StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DeviceConnectivity.Interop.ConManServerClass.ConnectDevice()
       at Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.Device.Connect()
       at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Documents and Settings\Thomas\Local Settings\Application Data\Temporary Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 23
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be found at `<systemdrive>:\Program files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\CoreCon\1.0\Bin`.

This is the path where you can get this dll, so add this dll to your project.

Answer (score 1):

Installing VS 2008 SP 1 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it works ok. Can you paste in the whole exception and stack trace?

**Updated:** Strangely I can't find that interop assy on my machine either other than under the c:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL folders.

Why not fire up SysInternals FileMon or Process Monitor, it'd save some guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is a problem with my Microsoft.VisualStudio.DeviceConnectivity.Interop assembly. There is no copy of that on disk that I can find. It's in the GAC only. I tried to inspect in Reflector, but it needs that Interop assembly also. Since ConManServerClass is obviously COM, maybe there's a COM library that has to be registered?